# Using a username starting "##" at a bash prompt

Tags: bash, ssh, sftp

Some clown made me a sftp username that started with ##.  Now I don't know if the command is wrong or the ftp server isn't responding for certain.  Could someone please confirm for me that this should work using:

sftp "##Username@sftphostaddress"

Thank you

Comment: I did finally get from another support person that the original person gave me the wrong ip.  It does work properly with the correct address.  I don't know if the person who gave me the wrong ip is the same one as is making username that start with "##" but I'm going to guess that's a yes.   :)

Comment: Normally, I'd slap an IT person for doing something like this, but in this case, it's pretty humourous so I'd probably let it slide LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that should work... if your username really does start with `##`. If it does, it would have to be the most bizarre username I've ever seen. In other words: are you sure this username is correct?

Comment: Thank you--Yeah, I've confirmed with the support staff of the company that that was indeed our username.  I didn't really know what else to say.  :/